# Access of undefined mx.core:FlexGlobals

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I would like to use `FlexGlobals`, but I always get this error.

> 1120: Access of undefined property FlexGlobals.
>
> 1172: Definition mx.core:FlexGlobals could not be found.

This is weird, because I think Flex Globals are part of the Flex 3.5 Framework.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FlexGlobals](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html) is released with Flash Builder SDK4,  you can use [mx.core.Application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html) in Flex 3

Should read [Migrating From Flex 3 to Flash Builder 4](http://Migrating%20From%20Flex%203%20to%20Flash%20Builder%204)

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 4):

You should place `import` directive the following way:

```
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
```

More information is [over here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#import).

Answer (score 1):

FlexGlobals is part of Flex 4 SDK

```
Package mx.core
Class   public class FlexGlobals
Inheritance FlexGlobals Inheritance Object

Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0
Product Version:    Flex 4
Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 10, AIR 1.5

A class that contains variables that are global to all applications within the same ApplicationDomain.
```